# What's the difference between data and data1 sections and the difference between rodata and rodata1 sections in a ELF file?

Tags: linker, elf

I checked ELF spec here http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f00/docs/elf.pdf But, there is no difference mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I am not finding a single document mandating this, but .rodata1 typically comes after everything starting with .rodata. You can look at the linker scripts on your system to verify this (usually /usr/lib/ldscripts/).

This makes some nice things possible, like placing a variable for a checksum in this section. This ensures its behind the remaining read-only stuff, a tool can then calculate the checksum and patch in into the binary.

During runtime you can check your code against the checksum. This sound stupid for a PC, but its common in embedded firmwares.
My guess the section was motivated by having a section "outside" of the code produced by a compiler for various reasons, but was never fully documented.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, they're the same.

It's also compiler-dependent. Some compilers will concatenate this 2 sections (and maybe more sections) into ".data".

Answer (score 1):

From some git archaeology in the binutils-gdb sources, it looks like:

The commit 252b5132c753 ("19990502 sourceware import") has a diff that mentions:

```
+Fri Jul 23 13:51:09 1993  Ken Raeburn  (raeburn@cambridge.cygnus.com)
+
+       * scripttempl/elf.sc: Add support for .init, .fini, .ctors,
+       .dtors, .data1, .rodata1 sections, instead of combining them into
+       other sections.  For `-r', set all section start addresses to
+       zero.
```

Is the earliest reference I can find. I suspect binutils was grafted into gdb's sources at that point.  I can't seem to find the pre-imported sources that existed 26+ years ago.  It seems their mail archives start at 1999. No bugs in their bug tracker for `rodata1`.